# Fade two elements exactly the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two elements which should appear at exactly the same time. I thought I could achieve it with this code:

```
$('.arrow-dock, .dropdown-menu', dropdown).stop(true, true).delay(delay).fadeIn("fast");
```

But it seems the different browsers execute the `fadeIn()` subsequently not simultaneously. There are different delays between the fades in different browsers.
Is there a way to start those fades at exactly the same time?

Comment: One of many, many reasons why I never animate with javascript. Why not just add a class to all of the elements and let CSS transitions handle the rest?

Comment: Can you do us a fiddle? My (very basic) example doesn't exhibit this behaviour. http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/xBB5x/13558/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't been able to replicate the issue where the elements don't fade together, however I can believe it's happening as animation with JS is rather unreliable if the DOM is large or there is a lot of processing already occurring.

To help fix the issue you could use CSS to perform the animation instead. This has the benefit of being hardware accelerated, so should suffer less under heavy loads. Try this:

```js
var dropdown = $('#dropdown');
$('.arrow-dock, .dropdown-menu', dropdown).addClass('show');
```

```css
#dropdown > div {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s opacity 1s;
}
#dropdown > div.show {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/81hyxtk9/)

Comment: In the first place I was looking for a possibility to synchronise actions in JavaScript. But I found out in my case CSS works as well. I don't even need to add a class with JavaScript because my action depends solely on hover.